# Jasper reports are missing in Eclipse metadata folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jaspersoft-studio

I am working on dynamic web project using Eclipse. I have created a report using Jaspersoft Studio. Now I am trying to access the same from my `jsp`. But i am getting below error:

> `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/kavi/dev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/inqc/Blank_A4_Landscape.jasper`

Please snap shows my report location. But as per above error, those files are missing in above path. So please someone help to resolve this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to access the file? Using `java.io.File`?

Try using the absolute path, something like `/home/kavi/dev/workspace/inqc/Blank_A4_Landscape.jasper` as opposed to navigating via the `.metadata` folder and see if it works.

***Update:***

A sample jsp file that reads text from a .txt file and prints it.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.io.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% 
        String s = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/Eclipse/workspace/Temp/sample.txt")));
            s = reader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>

    <p>String is <%=s %></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.. but how to define that path. By default its trying to access from .metadata!!

Comment: You can do something like this... `java.io.File file = new File("/home/kavi/dev/workspace/inqc/Blank_A4_Landscape.jasper")` and have this file wrapped in a `BufferedReader` or so as per your need. I have updated the answer with a sample jsp that reads text from a .txt file. Hope it helps.

Comment: Add the Jasper files into build path and try to access it, It may helps you